# Select2 rails does not applied to select_tag in form_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

I am working on rails 5 app. i am trying to load the data asynchronously form pgsql using **jquery-select2** data is loading perfectly on search. but the problem is, i want to show the select2 tag when radio button is selected. i have two [radio buttons][1]. code for radio buttons is following 
`

```
<%= radio_button(:new, :agent, :yes, { required: true, checked: true, 
     class: 'invite-rb' }) %>
<%= label_tag :new_agent_yes, 'New Agent' %>
<%= radio_button(:new, :agent, :no, { required: true, class: 'invite-rb' }) %>
<%= label_tag :new_agent_no, 'Existing Agent' %>`
```

I want to show the select2 box when user clicks on existing agent. but jquery-select2 is not applied to the select box.
here is my code for **agent.js**

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('.invite-rb').change(function() {
    if(this.value == 'yes'){ //when i change this value to 'no' every thing works perfectly but not working with this condition 
      $('#agents').removeAttr('required')
      $('#agent_first_name, #agent_last_name, #agent_email, #agency_code, #agent_code').attr('required', true)
      $('#existing-agent-fields').addClass('hidden')
      $('#new-agent-fields').removeClass('hidden')
      $('#applications-div').addClass('hidden')
    }
    else{
      $('#agent_first_name, #agent_last_name, #agent_email, #agent_agency_code, #agent_agent_code').removeAttr('required')
      $('#agents').attr('required', true)
      $('#existing-agent-fields').removeClass('hidden')
      $('#new-agent-fields').addClass('hidden')
      $('.chosen-select').select2()
      $('#applications-div').addClass('hidden')

      $('.chosen-select').select2({
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        placeholder: "Search by Agency code, agent code, name or email",
        ajax: {
          url: "/dashboard/agent_invitations/search_agents",
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'GET',
          data: function (term) {
            return { q: term }
          },
          processResults: function (data) {
            return { results: data.results }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

i don't know whats wrong with this conditions. i don't want to change the values assigned to radio buttons because complete logic of this page depends upon them.

agent.js  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYrel.png

Comment: are you rendering any partial in `search_agents.js.erb` ?

Comment: no. returning json object  `format.json {render json: { "results": current_salesperson.search_agents(params[:q][:term]) }}`